# Три уровня вложенности в TreeTableView JavaFX через HashMap

Tags: java, javafx, treeview, java-hashmap

У меня есть TreeTableView который я заполняю с помощью HashMap. Вот таким вот кодом:

```
 public void HashMapInUSD (){
    String MapInf = "SELECT category, name_score, defference FROM consolid";
    results = new HashMap<>();
   MathContext mc = new MathContext(10);
    try {
        Connection Map = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
        PreparedStatement FirstMap = Map.prepareStatement(MapInf);
        ResultSet rs = FirstMap.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String category = rs.getString(1);
            String name_score = rs.getString(2);
            BigDecimal difference = new BigDecimal(rs.getString(3));

            amount = amount.add(difference, mc);

            if (results.containsKey(category)) {
                Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = results.get(category);
                innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new ExpencesUSD(category, 
name_score, difference));
            }
            else {
                Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
               innerMap.put(new ExpencesUSD(category, category, BigDecimal.ZERO), new ArrayList<> 
());
                innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new ExpencesUSD(category, 
name_score, difference));
                results.put(category, innerMap);
            }
            Map.Entry<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = 
results.get(category).entrySet().iterator().next();
            innerMap.getKey().setTotal(innerMap.getKey().getTotal().add(difference));
        }
    }catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
   TreeItem<Expences> rootItem = new TreeItem(new ExpencesUSD(" ", "Данные", amount));
   results.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
       Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = entry.getValue();
       TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> categoryItem;
       categoryItem = new TreeItem(innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());
       rootItem.getChildren().add(categoryItem);
       innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().forEach(expenceInList -> {
           TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> scoreItem = new TreeItem(expenceInList);
           categoryItem.getChildren().add(scoreItem);
       });
   });
   expences.setRoot(rootItem);
 }
```

С помощью этого кода у меня получилось вывести из HashMap два уровня вложенности:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я дописал код:

```
public void HashMapInUsd(){
    String MapInf = "SELECT category, additional_score, name_score, difference_usd FROM consolid";
    Map<String, Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>>> resultsUSD;
    resultsUSD = new HashMap<>();
    MathContext mc = new MathContext(10);
    BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    try {
        Connection Map = DatabaseHandler.getDbConnection();
        PreparedStatement FirstMap = Map.prepareStatement(MapInf);
        ResultSet rs = FirstMap.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String category = rs.getString(1);
            String additional_score = rs.getString(2);
            String name_score = rs.getString(3);
            String differenceUsd = rs.getString(4);
            BigDecimal total = new BigDecimal(differenceUsd);
            amount = amount.add(total, mc);

            if (resultsUSD.containsKey(category)) {
                Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = resultsUSD.get(category);
                innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new ExpencesUSD(category, 
 additional_score, name_score, total));
            } else
                {
                Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();
                innerMap.put(new ExpencesUSD(category, category, additional_score, BigDecimal.ZERO), 
 new ArrayList<>());
                 innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(new ExpencesUSD(category, 
 additional_score, name_score, total));
                resultsUSD.put(category, innerMap);
            }
            Map.Entry<ExpencesUSD,List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = 
 resultsUSD.get(category).entrySet().iterator().next();
            innerMap.getKey().setTotalUsd(innerMap.getKey().getTotalUsd().add(total));
        }
    }catch (SQLException throwables) {
        throwables.printStackTrace();
    }
    TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> rootItem = new TreeItem(new ExpencesUSD("Данные USD", "Данные USD", 
amount));
    resultsUSD.entrySet().forEach(entry -> {
        Map<ExpencesUSD, List<ExpencesUSD>> innerMap = entry.getValue();
        TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> categoryItem;
        categoryItem = new TreeItem(innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getKey());
        rootItem.getChildren().add(categoryItem);

        innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().forEach(expenceInList -> {
            TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> scoreItem = new TreeItem(expenceInList);
            categoryItem.getChildren().add(scoreItem);

            innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().forEach(second -> {
                TreeItem<ExpencesUSD> secondItems2 = new TreeItem(second);
                scoreItem.getChildren().add(secondItems2);
            });
        });
    });
    expences_usd.setRoot(rootItem);
}
```

У меня получилось вывести три уровня вложенности но, сам список после открытия последнего уровня показывает одинаковую информацию: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что это и зачем оно так? `innerMap.entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().add(..)`

Comment: Заполняет в map value

Comment: map работает по принципу ключ-значение. То есть если вам надо добавить или получить значение из map, вам надо иметь ключ. Из кода, что вы показали, я думаю, вам надо чуть больше уделить внимания классу `HashMap<>` и как нужно с ним работать.